# Is it possible to install symfony framework in shared hosting environment ? If possible how do I set the webserver configs?

Tags: php, symfony1

Is it possible to install symfony framework in shared hosting environment ? If possible, how do I set the webserver configs in httpd.config as they describe in the docs ?

Thank  you

Comment: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/InstallingSymfonyOnSharedHostNoSsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an tutorial about Deployment: [Practical symfony - Day 22: The Deployment](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22)

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting in Symfony is possible ([complete instructions](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/InstallingSymfonyOnSharedHostNoSsh)), but not necessarily secure. From the [wiki](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SharedHostingNotSecure):

> If service you are using allows you to see the files of other customers you MUST NOT run the stock, out-of-the-box Symfony distribution in that environment. Symfony's cache manager creates world-writable PHP scripts in the cache folder. ANY CUSTOMER of the web host could overwrite those with scripts of their own and take over your site completely. It's not "if you get hacked." It's more like "when you get hacked."

Answer (score 0):

I would check out their [wiki](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki#Installingsymfony).  That link specifically points to the Installing Symfony section which has a few subsections talking about different environments.  The subsection you want to look at is Host.  There are 11 articles there about how to install on shared hosting and some gotchas to look out for.